# JavaScript: binding to a variable

Tags: javascript, programming-languages

This may be a naive but i am not able to understand how javascript assign values to its variables. In this [book](https://eloquentjavascript.net/05_higher_order.html), i came across the following code.

```
function greaterThan(n) {
return m => m > n;
}
let greaterThan10 = greaterThan(10);
console.log(greaterThan10(12));
```

How is **m** assigned the value 12 ? This does'nt give compile time as well as runtime error. Only if i remove **m =>**, i get an error that m is not 
defined.

Comment: `**` is the exponentiation operator. That syntax looks a bit invalid

Comment: google `currying` in `js` https://medium.com/front-end-hacking/javascript-es6-curry-functions-with-practical-examples-6ba2ced003b1

Comment: removed it. I added it for bold style

Comment: `return m => m > n` returns a function which takes a parameter `m` and returns whether `m` is greater than `n` (where `n` is a previously *closed over* value). So `greaterThan10` is such a function.

Comment: Understood. Thank you guys :)